# mongoid -> why asking ismaster every millisecond?

Tags: mongoid

database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} (4002.9714ms)
i see this happening every ms maybe I'm exaggerating it happens every 1s.

The problem is that when you have replicaset located in different physical locations you get slow responses on that query thats happening every second on all replicasets(btw, replicasets are not defined as hosts in mongoid config, but it figures them out from the replica set config, and starts the crazy task).

1-I'm wondering if i can turn that option off?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening to keep mongoid up to date on which node it should eventually write to. I believe this is an old version of Mongoid 3.0*. the newer versions should not have that problem.

I'm not also sure if newer versions of mongoid handles primary changes correctly.

I must say its always better to use the language driver! mongo ruby driver in this case!